# How are sparse matrices stored in Eigen?

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen3

How are sparse matrices stored in Eigen? I would like to know how are sparse matrices stored in Eigen when I assemble them using triplets? Are they stored in the compressed column storage or compressed row storage or some other format?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title0)?

Comment: @ggael My question should be reworded as follows. If I store as triplets, does Eigen convert it to compressed column/row format internally?

Comment: yes of course, the `setFromTriplets` method converts it to a compressed format.